# Cannot open synced Realm on Android with React Native

Tags: android, react-native, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-object-server

I'm trying to open a synced realm on React Native with a correctly logged in user like so:

```
Realm.open({
    sync: { user, url },
    schema,
    schemaVersion: 1
  })
```

On iOS, it works as expected. On Android, the call hangs without error message. Since it works on iOS and I don't have platform specific code, there should not be an error in the code.

I'm using realm react-native 1.10.0 and realm object server 1.8.3.

One thing worth mentioning is, I pre-fill the data into an read-only realm using the Java client 3.5.0. Might there be a compatibility issue between these versions?

Comment: Did you find an answer to your problem?

Comment: I think it was the chrome debugger. We always had issues with realm when chrome debugger is turned on. So, we switched to Reactotron and it works now

Answer (score 0):

Use Reactron debugger instead of chrome as for now realm does not work well with Google Chrome Debug tools